# How can I move fast in CLI in Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

In linux in CLI I can press ALT + F or ALT + B to move back and forth in terms of words and not one character at a time.
Is this available in Mac?
There is no ALT and I tried Control + F, Fn + F, Command + F  but it does not work.
BTW I am using the default console installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to skin this cat.

Firstly, there is an <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, but depending on the age of your Mac/keyboard is may be called <kbd>Option</kbd> or look like <kbd>⌥</kbd>.  Using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>◀︎</kbd> or <kbd>▶︎</kbd> will move a word at a time using a default shell in the default `terminal` app.

Secondly, you can tell your shell of choice to use alternate methods.  If you have ever used `vi` and are used to its weird methods of navigation <kbd>w</kbd> to move forward a word, <kbd>b</kbd> to go back,<kbd>W</kbd> to move forward a sentence and so on, then you can tell it to use those instead by typing `set -o vi` into your shell, now the first method doesn't work, and the weirdy `vi` method is used instead.

In addition, in `Settings > Settings > Keyboard` (on Mavericks at least) you can tick this little fella to bring back your <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> behaviour:

[image]

There are probably way more methods too, it depends on your shell and your shell options basically.